# Always keep a selected item in a iron-list

Tags: polymer

```
<iron-list id="list" class="flex" items="{{data}}" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" x="[[itemChanged(selectedItem)]]" selection-enabled>
    <template>
        <div class$="[[_computedClass(selected)]]">
            <span class="flex">test</span>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-list>
```

The solution I am looking for is like a radio group where there is always one selection in the iron-list.

I tried

```
itemChanged: function() {
    if (this.selectedItem) {
        this.selected = this.$.list.items.indexOf(this.selectedItem);
    } else {
        if(this.selected != null) { this.$.list.selectItem(this.selected);}
    }
},
```

This ends up in a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Comment: I have no clue about what a iron-list might be, but it looks to me that when you set `this.selected` the `itemChanged` is called again, thus creating an infinit loop. Put  a `console.log` at the start of `itemChanged` to see if that is the case.

Comment: This is a iron list https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list. And you are correct that it end up in a loop, because selectItem changes the item again. That said, stil not clear to me what a trival polymer solution would be. I can maybe come up with yet a other variable to prevent a loop, but it all makes it so complex for something simple.

Comment: well the obvious solution to this problem would be not to change `selected` in the `itemChanged` function.

Comment: Also my two cents with frameworks: dump them as soon as you start struggling more with the framework instead of your application. So far i only found flex useful (out of the whole ember,backbase,that google thingie.. forest of things doing to much magic), and you cant even call that a framework..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implemenation of this behaviour:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <style>
        .selected {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
        }
        iron-list {
            height: 200px;
            width:200px
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <iron-list id="list" items="[[data]]" as="item"  selection-enabled on-selected-item-changed="itemChanged">
            <template>
                <div class$="[[_computedClass(selected)]]">[[item.name]]</div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "test-element",
        properties: {
            data: {type: Array,
                notify: true,
                value: function() { return [
                    {"name": "Bob"},
                    {"name": "Tim"},
                    {"name": "Mike"}
                ]
                        ;}
            },
            last: Object
         },
        ready: function(){
            this.last = this.data[0];
        },
        itemChanged: function(){
            if (this.$.list.selectedItem === null) {
                this.async(function(){
                    if (this.$.list.selectedItem === null) {
                        this.$.list.selectItem(this.last);
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                this.last = this.$.list.selectedItem;
            }
        },
        _computedClass : function(selected) {
            return selected? "selected": "";
        }

    });
</script>
```

The relevant bit is in the `itemChanged`changed function.
One thing that made it tricky, is the fact that the iron-list will trigger two events for each selection. First, it will unselect the previously selected item and then select the new item. So in order to figure out if no new item is selected, you have to wait and see if a new selection event is triggered. That's what I'm using the `async` for. Then I also store a reference to the previously selected item in the `last` property. In case no new item is selected, I restore the selection to the last selection.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What a pain :-(. I just came to that solution after quite some debugging and checked the web if there is a saner way, but this seems the way to go. See also https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/100

Comment: I agree. This is more of a workaround than a proper solution that I would want to use in production.